# Translate Nginx rewrite rule to Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

Help with changing code in Nginx, I would like to pass it to .htaccess, is that possible?

```
location ~ ^/api/(?:tickets|tasks|auth).*$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /api/http.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Nginx doesn't use `.htaccess` files.  They're not great anyway... they require the server to parse and reload config every request.

Comment: sorry, I got confused in the title, is to convert that code in Nginx to .htaccess